# Is it possible for a v1.compute.instances.insert to initially succeed, only to fail a few seconds later?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I experienced something strange today, where creating new compute instances appeared to initially succeed, only to fail behind-the-scenes a few seconds later:

[image]

You can see at 16:31:33, the insert apparently succeeded, with the response status set to `RUNNING`. However, 9 seconds later there's another trace saying the insert failed with reason `ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED`. The problem is that my program doesn't know anything is wrong - it thinks the instance is running, when in reality it never successfully inserted. I didn't think this was possible until today. Is this really possible or is there likely a bug in my program? I do not see the `-234` instance in compute engine and I do not see any `v1.compute.instances.delete` log traces on it, so I'm at a loss at how I'm supposed to detect these sorts insertion failures in the future.

Comment: The API returns an operation handle. Check for status on the operation handle to determine the final result.

Comment: I was using `func (c *InstancesInsertCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)` in the golang sdk so I just assumed if the returned error was `nil` then it meant insertion was successful... I'll check the contents of the returned `*Operation` though to see if it provides additional satus.

Comment: First, you must wait for the status to complete, then check the error.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I needed to do: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/samples/compute-instances-operation-check#compute_instances_operation_check-go

Answer (score 2):

It takes time to provision the resources and to receive a response. Therefore, rather than thinking it created an instance and then got deleted, it is more like GCP started provisioning the instances, but was unable to do so due to the insufficient resources issue and then finally responded, ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED error.

As the [ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability) means that the resources that you are trying to use are unavailable in the specified zone and cannot accommodate the request.

You may try to deploy in other regions or zones.

Or try the [reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview) feature which can provide a very high level of assurance in obtaining capacity for Compute Engine zonal resources.

You may refer at this documentation for details on [creating a reservation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-single-project) and this documentation for details on [consuming reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources#consuming_reserved_instances).

Comment: Yes, my problem was that I was not waiting for the operation to complete before checking whether insertion was successful: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/samples/compute-instances-operation-check#compute_instances_operation_check-go

Comment: I did upvote but I did not accept it since his answer didn't solve my issue; your comment did. If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.